# In iphone ios 7.0.4 app crashes when Launch the app

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

i made a game using cocos 2d. it's work fine in iOS 5 and 6 but it crashes when launching the app to the splash screen in ios 7.0.4 on device. i developed the game in xocde 4.6.1. I have a crash log report.

---

```
Incident Identifier: CE1591CE-8C42-4A28-B9BC-475D2DA3D003
CrashReporter Key:   2052fa255b4c1ef610c06e87282541732110f760
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Fly Paradise [4247]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/2E646AFF-51C0-42F0-83CE-D5B901CF248E/Fly Paradise.app/Fly Paradise
Identifier:          com.spinytel.Fly-Paradise
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-12-09 19:50:55.199 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x16b2564d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Fly Paradise                    0x000fcfdc 0xa4000 + 364508
1   Fly Paradise                    0x000fd2f4 0xa4000 + 365300
2   Fly Paradise                    0x000fef0c 0xa4000 + 372492
3   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff126 0xa4000 + 373030
4   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff4f8 0xa4000 + 374008
5   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff770 0xa4000 + 374640
6   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff932 0xa4000 + 375090
7   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff9f6 0xa4000 + 375286
8   Fly Paradise                    0x000ff9c6 0xa4000 + 375238
9   Fly Paradise                    0x000f9ce4 0xa4000 + 351460
10  Fly Paradise                    0x000ec1f4 0xa4000 + 295412
11  Fly Paradise                    0x000ed8ac 0xa4000 + 301228
12  UIKit                           0x329bfd9e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
13  QuartzCore                      0x32646c66 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
14  QuartzCore                      0x32642476 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
15  QuartzCore                      0x326715c0 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 136
16  UIKit                           0x32a3c9de -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 238
17  UIKit                           0x32a3b046 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 3494
18  UIKit                           0x32a3a296 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 42
19  UIKit                           0x32a3a21e -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 90
20  UIKit                           0x32a3a1b6 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 38
21  UIKit                           0x32a32cb4 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 104
22  UIKit                           0x329c5db4 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 380
23  UIKit                           0x32a39f04 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 692
24  UIKit                           0x32a399d0 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 160
25  UIKit                           0x329caf90 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 460
26  UIKit                           0x329c84d6 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
27  UIKit                           0x32a33088 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
28  Fly Paradise                    0x000fa142 0xa4000 + 352578
29  UIKit                           0x32a302fa -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 270
30  UIKit                           0x32a2fd4a -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1386
31  UIKit                           0x32a2a34e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 710
32  UIKit                           0x329c541a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3126
33  UIKit                           0x329c471c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
34  UIKit                           0x32a29b38 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 660
35  GraphicsServices                0x34e8270a _PurpleEventCallback + 606
36  GraphicsServices                0x34e822f2 PurpleEventCallback + 30
37  CoreFoundation                  0x302179dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
38  CoreFoundation                  0x30217976 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
39  CoreFoundation                  0x3021614a __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
40  CoreFoundation                  0x30180c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
41  CoreFoundation                  0x30180a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
42  UIKit                           0x32a28dd4 -[UIApplication _run] + 756
43  UIKit                           0x32a24044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
44  Fly Paradise                    0x000f9c06 0xa4000 + 351238
45  libdyld.dylib                   0x3afcbab4 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f83c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3afb0210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3afaff96 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b082c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x302177be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30215ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30180c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30180a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x38370266 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eac1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eab8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x302177be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30215ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30180c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30180a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2f203584 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2f1f799c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eac1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eab8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f888 mach_msg + 44
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2fc02116 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 102
3   AudioToolbox                    0x2fc05348 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
4   AudioToolbox                    0x2fb42ba8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eac1a _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eab8a _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b06f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x302177be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30215ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30180c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30180a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   AudioToolbox                    0x2fb5c754 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   AudioToolbox                    0x2fb42ba8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eac1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0eab8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0e8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0000000c    r1: 0x00000251      r2: 0x16b2564d      r3: 0x0000024d
    r4: 0x15dabbb0    r5: 0x15dae4f0      r6: 0x341e8dff      r7: 0x27d59028
    r8: 0xffffffff    r9: 0x15dabfb8     r10: 0x15dabbb0     r11: 0x001ae06c
    ip: 0x000fcd69    sp: 0x27d59024      lr: 0x000fcfb9      pc: 0x000fcfdc
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

---

How can I solve this issue? Could it be a problem with the build settings?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to symbolicate first - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1460892/1445366

Answer (score 0):

Without symbolicating the crash log and viewing some code associated with the methods that appears in the symbolicated carshlog where it crashed, there is nothing we can do.

Do the usual to debug it (create an exception breakpoint, test on simulator, symbolicate your crashlog to have the method names instead of just their addresses, use LLDB/GDB to debug when it crashes, etc)

Answer (score 0):

make sure config below

"PROJECT" -> "Architectures":Standard architectures(armv7,armv7s)